# Clicking a button within an IE table

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to click a button within a table on a webpage within IE, the source of the button shows:

```
<input type="image" src="img/testimg.png" onclick="picture_return(this,'92b84574a336a090618f151b6fc821cf:5','http://testwebpage.com/in/834');" value="Test Web Button">
```

This is a part of a large table with multiple `<td>` within the source, this is within another table which is then within the following class:

```
<div class="section_client_dnBox">
```

I tried to go through a few of the items within the class by using the following VBA code:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("section_client_dnBox")(0).Click
```

However, had no luck as (0) didn't press anything and anything larger ie, (1) gave me an error. So my question now is basically, is there any way of clicking the button using something simple such as reffering to it's value within the table (value="Test Web Button")?

Comment: Just out of curiosity--why are you using VBA when 99.9% of the rest of the internet is using JS?

Comment: The purpose of this code is for IE automation. I am not sure if this is easily achieved using JS and also I dont have much experience with JS.

Comment: For what particular task?  Testing a webpage/application?  Screen scraping?  I think you're far better off using JS, as it works on all browsers and can do pretty much anything you need.  There's going to be far more community support for it when you need help, as well--very few people use VBA for anything these days.

Comment: @mpowered while I agree that JS may be better for this application, I know quite a few people who would disagree about "very few people use VBA for anything these days". VBA is alive and well. Many many people professionally use VBA as it remains the best option for many many Office Automation needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, you need to look at the tag name rather than the class name. This is an example of the code I generally use when finding buttons.

```
For Each MyHTML_Element In document.getElementsByTagName("input")
     If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then
         MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
     End If
Next
```

You might be able to change the . type to  = "image". I too am just learning how to use IE automation in  VBA so I am not a champ at it either. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

It is far simpler to use a CSS selector of `input[value='Test Web Button']`. No loop required.

It says get element with `input` tag having attribute `value` having value = `'Test Web Button'`. `"[]"` means attribute.

`.querySelector` method of `document` is how you apply the selector.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[value='Test Web Button']").Click
```